# Сворачивание CollapsingToolBar без NestedScrollView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-toolbar, collapsing-toolbar-layout

На `Activity` есть `AppBarLayout` c `CollapsingToolbarLayout` в котором находится фильтр в виде `LinearLayout` co спиннером и кнопкой. Кнопка имеет видимость `GONE` и становится видимой только при определенном выборе из списка спиннера.

Под `AppBarLayout` находится `FrameLayout` в котором заменяются фрагменты, в которых есть `RecyclerView`.

Я пытаюсь свернуть `CollapsingToolbarLayout` при прокрутке `RecyclerView`, чтобы фильтр не занимал много места, а по возможности свернуть и `Toolbar`.

Если я оберну FrameLayout в NestedScrollView то да, все будет работать должным образом, но так делать нельзя, т.к. приложение падает при большом количестве элементов. Собственно и сам вопрос: Как можно свернуть `CollapsingToolbarLayout`   без `NestedScrollView`?

Или может есть идеи реализации без `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я потратил пол дня на поиск какой-нибудь информации, а потом просто вспомнил, что nested scroll был отключен.

Установка `mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);` решила проблему